# JavaScript get substring starting from and ending to specific chars

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a file signature in JavaScript which is a string that starts from `SHA` and ends at some value:

```
SHA256-RSA-V1,140f3059eac,384,urn:alx:uid:09bd9e42-0348-4c35-910d-2d7fdaa2,1, ...
```

I want only this part: `urn:alx:uid:09bd9e42-0348-4c35-910d-2d7fdaa2`

It will always start from `urn`, which I know, but before the comma, the value can be anything.

How to get the substring exactly from the `urn` till the comma in JavaScript ?

Edit:
I tried splitting the string from `,` but there can be a lot of commas and code gets messy. I couldn't get a regex from the `urn` to the first comma. After the first comma, I want to stop.

Comment: Please read "[What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)"

Comment: Use a regex like "SHA.*(urn:[^,]*)".  Also, consider tagging your post so it is categorized properly.

Comment: @x3ro, I have tried regex only. I need better regex. Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

I would use following regular expression:

```
(urn:alx:uid:[a-f0-9-]+)
```

Example: http://regexr.com?3681h

or alternative:

```
(urn:alx:uid:[^,]+)
```

Example: http://regexr.com?3681k

Both are equal in this case so choose the one you better understand.

Comment: `(urn:[^,]+)` worked. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions

```
string = "SHA256-RSA-V1,140f3059eac,384,urn:alx:uid:09bd9e42-0348-4c35-910d-2d7fdaa2"
var matches = string.match(/urn.*\,/);
alert(matches[1]);
```

Comment: Nopes. Running your code on a tring like this `SHA256-RSA-V1,140f3059eac,384,urn:alx:uid:09bd9e42-0348-4c35-910d-2d7fdaa2,1,22342534,5`, gives me matches as an array with all commas. I want to stop at first comma

Answer (score 0):

If you know that ,urn: and a comma are always in the string, you could do something like this

str = "SHA256-RSA-V1,140f3059eac,384,urn:alx:uid:09bd9e42-0348-4c35-910d-2d7fdaa2,1,random";
result = "urn:" + str.split(",urn:").slice(1).join().split(",")[0];

---

or you can use regular expressions

str = "SHA256-RSA-V1,140f3059eac,384,urn:alx:uid:09bd9e42-0348-4c35-910d-2d7fdaa2,1,random";
str.match(/urn:.+?,/);